# -1 point on a page where I have never interacted

Tags: support

Can someone kindly shade some light on this?

I see a "-1" reputation in my history from this page:

[How to get a complete list of ticker symbols from Yahoo Finance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246843/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-ticker-symbols-from-yahoo-finance/5246991#5246991)

But I do not recall having ever commented or answered the question. 
I have checked in all my actions and the page is not mentioned.

[image: -1]

Comment: Sounds like you downvoted an answer on this page, that's the only action costing 1 rep I can think of.

Comment: @Tensibai Alright, thanks. That must be it... It raises the question "what incentive I have on downvoting bad content" but I'll leave that for another day :)

Comment: There's multiple reason, you get your rep back when the post is deleted, and the post has to be -3 to be deleted by 20k+ users. And that's just 1 point, it cost to avoid people downvoting other's competitive answers mostly.

Comment: Since the -1 cost for downvoting an answer is covered in the FAQ, I'm marking this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Tensibai small correction: answer has to be at -1 in order for 20k rep user to be able to cast delete vote. The -3 is the required threshold for 20k user to be able to delete a closed question without waiting few days. :)